# Георгівна чи Георгіївна?

Tags: вибір-слова

Як правильно написати по батькові "Георгівна" чи "Георгіївна", адже в інтернеті я знаходив можливі як перший ([1](http://www.ktpp.chnu.edu.ua/index.php?page=ua/02personnel&data[9382][caf_pers_id]=1329&commands[9382]=item),[2](https://clarity-project.info/edr/2052806304/history)) так і другий варіанти ([1](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0),[2](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0)). Однак, якщо ввести в гуглі слово "Георгівна", то він видасть запит "Можливо ви мали на увазі "Георгіївна",  а також інформація на цьому [сайті](https://kak-pravilno.net/georgiyivna-chi-georgiyevna-yak-pravilno/) підтверджує, що має бути "Георгіївна".

Отож, як має бути правильно, адже варіант "Георгівна" поширений в Інтернеті (зустрічається наівть на офіційному сайті Чернівецького національного університету, на якому усе б мало відповідати нормам української мови), однак все ж таки більше фактів вказують на те, що має бути "Георгіївна".

Answer (score 2):

УМІФ НАНУ має лиш [*Георгіївна*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Довідом є і чинний [правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par22p10):

> *Правопис суфіксів → Іменникові суфікси → § 22*
>
> **-ОВИЧ, -ІВН(А) [-ЇВН(А)]**
>
> При творенні жіночих імен по батькові вживається суфікс **-івн(а)**, від імен на **-й** — **-ївн(а)**: *Борисівна, Василівна; Гордіївна, Сергіївна, Юріївна.*
>
> Від таких імен, як *Григорій*, *Ілля*, *Кузьма*, *Лука*, *Микола*, *Сава*, *Хома*, *Яків*, відповідні імена по батькові будуть: *Григорович*, *Григорівна*; *Ілліч*, *Іллівна*; *Кузьмич* (і *Кузьмович*), *Кузьмівна*; *Лукич*, *Луківна*; *Миколайович* (і *Миколович*), *Миколаївна* (і *Миколівна*); *Савич* (і *Савович*), *Савівна*; *Хомич* (і *Хомович*), *Хомівна*; *Якович*, *Яківна*.

Очевидно, що основою є *Георгій*, котре закінчується на **й**, отже тут теж ***Георгіївна***. Цікаво, що в прикладах наводиться утворення від подібної основи: [*Григорівна*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0), без льоґічного і теж затвердженого [*Григоріївна*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0). Однак, схоже, приклади є винятками [[1]](http://cpk.org.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=606)[[2]](http://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/creation_surname.html).

---

Розсуд правопису і не відповідь. Слушне зауваження пана [kreiri](/users/767/):

> *Григорівна* може бути від *Григір*, а не *Григорій*.

Оскільки словником цїлком затверджені льоґічні для *Григорія*: [*Григорійович*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) і згадане *Григоріївна*. А льогічне імʼя для *Григорович* і згадане *Григорівна* теж затверджене: [Григір](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%80). Чергування голосних *і—о* допустимо для імен:

> [Примітка.](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par22p10prym) При творенні імен по батькові в основах імен відбувається чергування **і** з **о**: *Антін* — *Антонович*, *Антонівна*; *Федір* — *Федорович*, *Федорівна*.

Отже так має працювати. Але правопис і мовні джерела чомусь такого не припускають і твердять своє. Тут вже можемо помітити ще хибу словника УМІФ НАНУ: *Георгівна*, як і *Георгович*, котрих словник не має, цїлком можуть існувати при іменї [*Георг*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3), котрого словник вже включає.

Comment: "Григорівна" може бути від "Григір", а не "Григорій".

Comment: Я думаю, що «Правопис» стверджує «Григорій → Григорович/Григорівна» тому, що не вважає Григорій і Григір різними іменами. Вважати щось різними іменами чи варіантами одного імені — то доволі суб'єктивна річ, що може змінюватися з часом (Єгор раніше було формою від Георгій, а Олесь досі часто вживають як форму від Олексій/Олександр). Причин остаточно виділяти Григорій і Григір як два різні імені я справді поки що не бачу (брати-письменники — радше виняток; чого немає, то це потоку сучасних людей, що казали б «ні, не називай мене Григорій, я Григір», «ні, не називай мене Григір, я Григорій»).

Comment: Батька Тараса Шевченка, здається, звали іменем Григорій (принаймні, у [метричній книзі російською](http://izbornyk.org.ua/shevchenko/docum02.htm)).